# Expected value in EPR

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I was trying to read this paper http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/3714/1/epr-bell-iep-preprint.pdf and I would like to prove the Equations (1), (2) but I am not so good for quantum mechanics so I would like your help. I understand that operator A is the orthonormal projector $$A|a+\rangle|a+\rangle=|a+\rangle|a+\rangle,\quad A|a+\rangle|a-\rangle=|a+\rangle|a-\rangle\quad \mbox{ and }\quad A|a-\rangle|a+\rangle=A|a-\rangle|a-\rangle=0,$$ where $|a\pm\rangle=\psi_{\pm a}$ and B is similar for $|b\pm\rangle$. Since $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ with $|\psi\rangle=1/\sqrt2 \,(|a+\rangle|a-\rangle-|a-\rangle|a+\rangle)$ (this state is rotation-invariant) $$tr(A\rho)=\langle a+|\langle a+|A\rho\,|a+\rangle|a+\rangle+\langle a+|\langle a-|A\rho\,|a+\rangle|a-\rangle+\langle a-|\langle a+|A\rho\,|a-\rangle|a+\rangle+\langle a-|\langle a-|A\rho\,|a-\rangle|a-\rangle $$ $$=1/\sqrt2\,\langle a+|\langle a-|A|\psi\rangle-1/\sqrt2\,\langle a-|\langle a+|A|\psi\rangle=1/2\,\langle a+|a+\rangle\langle a-|a-\rangle=1/2.$$ This is correct?. For the other equation $$tr(AB\rho)=\langle a+|\langle a+|AB\rho\,|a+\rangle|a+\rangle+\langle a+|\langle a-|AB\rho\,|a+\rangle|a-\rangle$$ $$+\langle a-|\langle a+|AB\rho\,|a-\rangle|a+\rangle+\langle a-|\langle a-|AB\rho\,|a-\rangle|a-\rangle $$ and considering $$\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=1/2\,((|b+\rangle|b-\rangle-|b-\rangle|b+\rangle)(\langle a+|\langle a-|-\langle a-|\langle a+|)...(*)$$ I get $$tr(AB\rho)=1/2\,\langle a+|b+\rangle \langle a-|b-\rangle$$ but I do not know how I can continue to get that $tr(AB\rho)=1/2\, sin^2(\theta_{ab}/2)$. Is the equation (*) correct? I really do not know if it is possible to write $|\psi\rangle$ in terms of the basis $\{|a_\pm\rangle \}$ and $\langle \psi|$ in terms of the basis $\{\langle b_\pm|\}$ at the same time.